# SDP relaxation with greater-than and less-than inequalities at the same time

Tags: constraint, quadratic-programming, nonconvex-programming, relaxation, sdp

I am dealing with the following nonconvex fractional quadratic optimization problem

\begin{align}
  & \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} && \max_{t \in \mathcal{T}} \frac{\boldsymbol{a}_t^T \boldsymbol{x}}{\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{Q}_t\boldsymbol{x}}& \\
   & && x_j\in\{0,1\},  & j = 1,\dots,N
\end{align}

where $\boldsymbol{x}=[x_1,\dots,x_N]^T$, $\boldsymbol{a}_t = [a_{1t},\dots,a_{Nt}]^T\, \forall t \in \mathcal{T}$ and $\boldsymbol{Q}_t \in \mathbb{R}_+^{N \times N} \, \forall t \in \mathcal{T}$ is a stricly lower triangular (positive semidefinite) matrix.
By applying the SDP relaxation together with the linearization of the binary constraint, I get the following

\begin{align}
  & \min_{\boldsymbol{X}} && \max_{t \in \mathcal{T}} \frac{\text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{X} \odot \text{diag}(\boldsymbol{a}_t))} {\text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{Q}_t\boldsymbol{X})} & \\
   & && \boldsymbol{X} \succeq \boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^T\\
   & && X_{jj} \in [0, 1]  & j = 1,\dots,N 
\end{align}

with $\text{Tr}$ being the trace of a square matrix, $\text{diag}$ indicating a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is made out of the function argument and $\odot$ denoting the Hadamard product. To write the numerator, I exploit the property $X_{jj} = x_j$, being $x_j$ binary in the original problem.

The relaxed problem can be solved by means of the bisection method, so I can write a series of feasibility problems for decreasing values of a predefined threshold $z$ and solve them until the problem gets infeasible. I use CVX for this task.

\begin{align}
  & \text{Find} && \boldsymbol{X} && \\
   & && \text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{X} \odot \text{diag}(\boldsymbol{a}_t)) \leq z\, \text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{Q}_t\boldsymbol{X}) & \forall t \in \mathcal{T}\\
   & && \boldsymbol{X} \succeq \boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^T\\
   & && X_{jj} \in [0, 1]  & j = 1,\dots,N 
\end{align}

I pick the last feasible solution $\boldsymbol{X}^*$ as solution of the SDP relaxation. For simplicity, I use the Eigenvalue Decomposition (EVD) procedure to derive a rank-1 solution $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}$ from $\boldsymbol{X}^*$. In particular, after approximating $\boldsymbol{X}^*$ as $\lambda_1 \boldsymbol{q}_1 \boldsymbol{q}_1^T$, where $\lambda_1$ is its highest eigenvalue and $\boldsymbol{q}_1$ the corresponding eigenvector, I set $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}} = \sqrt{\lambda_1}\boldsymbol{q}_1$.

To enforce constraints $x_j < 1$, I would perform the normalization $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}/\max_j \sqrt{|\hat{x_j}|}$ and then obtain a binary solution $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ by quantization.

It is not clear to me if I am ignoring constraints $x_j > 0$ or if not, why. Moreover, in another version of this problem, I have a constraint of type $\text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{X}) \ge n, \, k\in \mathbb{N}$, which is a greater-than constraint. How is it to be treated with respect to the other constraints? How would you treat greater-than and less-than constraints if present at the same time? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show more details of how you go from the SDP formulation to the rank-1 solution?

Comment: Sure. I perform the Eigenvalue Decomposition of the solution of the SDP relaxation $\boldsymbol{X}^*$. Then, I approximate it as $\boldsymbol{X}^* \approx \lambda_1 \boldsymbol{q}_1 \boldsymbol{q}_1^T$, where $\lambda_1$ is the highest eigenvalue  and  $\boldsymbol{q}_1$ is the corresponding eigenvector. Finally, I set $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}} = \sqrt{\lambda_1} \boldsymbol{q}_1$.

Comment: How are you solving the SDP relaxation?  You should all all these details to the question itself, not just in comments.

Comment: Are you enforcing $X_{i,i}=x_i$? Also, if your rounded solution has negative coefficients, you could try a doubly non-negative relaxation instead of the usual SDP relaxation (i.e. adding the constraint $X \geq 0$ elementwise).

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I've added more details to the solution.

Comment: @RyanCory-Wright I'm using that equality to write the numerator of the objective function of the SDP relaxation. My rounded solution is feasible for the original problem but to me it is not completely clear why, as I am not explicitly enforcing constraints $\boldsymbol{X} \geq 0$.

Comment: How do you avoid the solution $X = 0, x = 0$ which is feasible for any $z$?

Comment: and out of curiosity, what dimensions are you addressing? (considering the fact that this problem can be solved rather easily in small dimensions using a MISOCP solver)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I actually don't avoid it. Can I solve $\max_{\boldsymbol{X}} \text{Tr}(\boldsymbol{X})$ instead of testing the feasibility with $\text{Find} \, \boldsymbol{X}$?
I'm solving a rather small instance ($T = 1e4$, $N = 1e2$) but I'd like to have a fairly scalable solution with SDP.

Comment: That means you are using heuristic which just as well could take a random X since the solution returned by the solver is completely undefined now. Since you know some element of the binary vector $x$ has to be non-zero (undefined objective otherwise), you can add $\sum x \geq 1$ to your model.

Comment: and note that for the case when the optimal $z$ is negative, the quadratic inequality is convex, and no reason to explode he problem size by lifting and relaxing the quadratic set.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg so that constraint would translate to $\text{Tr}(X) \geq 1$ and it would eventually prevent the optimal $z$ from being negative, I guess. My question then would be how I can enforce such constraint on the rank-1 solution obtained by the EVD. Thank you.

Comment: I would say that those are two different things. You first setup a relaxation which you try to make as strong as possible, and then you use what ever heuristics to recover a good solution from that relaxation. Just because you added that cut on the relaxation, does not necessarily mean you must enforce it in the heuristics.

Comment: All right. My understanding was that I had to enforce the tightest constraint on the rank-1 solution, which is the reason for $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}/\max_j \sqrt{|\hat{x_j}|}$. In the case of an additional greater-than constraint, I had no idea how to identify the tighest one. 
So, I just come up with whatever heuristics to satisfy the constraints of the original problem. Thank you!